# Inconsistent Meteor event handling with Semantic UI Button

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

I ran into a really odd bug today while writing a simple login form and formatting via Semantic UI.

**Here's the template:**

```
<div class="ui form attached fluid segment">
  <form name="loginForm">

    <div class="field">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="loginEmail" placeholder="bruce.li@shaolin.com">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="loginPassword" placeholder="Shh...">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="ui blue submit button" value="Login">

  </form>
</div>
```

**Here's the event handler:**

```
Template.login.events({ 
  "submit form": function( event, template ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var userEmail = event.target.loginEmail.value;
    var userPassword = event.target.loginPassword.value;

    Meteor.loginWithPassword( userEmail, userPassword );
    event.target.reset();

    FlowRouter.go( "newsfeed-view" );
  }
});
```

All this works perfectly fine until you start **changing/removing the button**. If i were to change  to  or remove the button, then the submit event will not work. However, other events such as click do work with or without the button.

Comment: An input with `type="submit"` fires the submit event. What are you expecting to happen when you don't have a button that fires the submit event?

Comment: That's not true. You can definitely create a plain form without type = "submit" and the event will be caught upon submission